# Google Reporting API ReportRequest cannot get all URL to count pageviews

Tags: c#, google-reporting-api

I'm using Google Reporting API and C# client to get all pageviews of some urls in my page
Example of urls:

```
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html  
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html
```

But in Google Analytics I can see my urls come with multiple query string

```
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html  
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html?q=1
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html?q=1
```

When I use C# request to Reporting API

```
var dimensionFilter = new DimensionFilter
                {
                    DimensionName = "ga:pagePath",
                    Expressions = pagePathList,
                    Operator__ = "IN_LIST"
                };
                var dimensionFilterClause = new DimensionFilterClause();
                dimensionFilterClause.Filters = new List<DimensionFilter> { dimensionFilter };

                //Get required View Id from configuration
                var ViewId = "xxxxxxxxxx";

                // Create the Request object.
                var reportRequest = new ReportRequest
                {
                    DateRanges = new List<DateRange> { dateRange },
                    Metrics = metrics,
                    Dimensions = dimensions,
                    ViewId = ViewId,
                    PageSize = 25000,
                    DimensionFilterClauses = new List<DimensionFilterClause> { dimensionFilterClause },
                };
                var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest();
                getReportsRequest.ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest };
```

Reporting API return only the exact urls in the list not full urls with query string because the operator "IN_LIST"

Example
In Google Analytics

```
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html: 100 pageviews
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html?q=1: 50 pageviews
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html: 20 pageviews
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html?q=1: 30 pageviews
```

Query return

```
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html: 100 pageviews
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html: 20 pageviews
```

It should be

```
/relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html: 150 pageviews (combine /relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html and /relative-path-1/title-of-url-ar1234.html ?q=1)
/relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html: 50 pageviews (combine /relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html and /relative-path-2/title-of-url-2-ar1234.html)
```

How can I get all pageviews of urls not only exact one in the list
I tried to change the operator to "PARTIAL" but the expression can not be a list of urls
Thanks

Comment: Check the status code in the response and see if you are getting 200 OK.  You may be getting 100 Continue which means you are using http 1.1 and not http 1.0.  You may need to add to your request to force to use http 1.0.

Comment: @jdweng my request success but it cannot count all pageviews, not http

Comment: Are you posting the strings in the response?  The items after the question marks are parameter in the query.  So ?q=1 is the parameter q with a value of 1.  check the headers in the request to see what is different in your request and the working request.  Then add missing headers/parameters to your code.

Comment: @jdweng I think you miss understood.  
I added example to the question, you want to look over it

Comment: Google Analytics has additional parameters in the query the you do not have.  So Google Analytics is getting a different response.  Look at documentation on Google Analytics and check what the q parameter is used for.  I suspect it is quantity.

Comment: @jdweng q is sample for query string that add by others, I don't know what it is

Comment: I suspect your query is just returning a summary line while the Google Analytics is querying for detail info.  The request determines what is returned in the response.  So Google Analytics is using a different parameter in the request which can be seen in the request headers.

Comment: @jdweng Yep, it the summary line, but the summary lack of pageviews of urls come with query string (coz IN_LIST operator only count exact urls)

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the request to see what you are missing.